# How to model type-safe enum types?

Tags: scala, enums

Scala doesn't have type-safe `enum`s like Java has. Given a set of related constants, what would be the best way in Scala to represent those constants?

Comment: Why not just using java enum? This is one of the few things I still prefer to use plain java.

Comment: I've written a small overview about scala Enumeration and alternatives, you may find it useful: pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-enums/

Answer (score 188, accepted):

http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/Enumeration.html

Example use

```
  object Main extends App {

    object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
      type WeekDay = Value
      val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
    }
    import WeekDay._

    def isWorkingDay(d: WeekDay) = ! (d == Sat || d == Sun)

    WeekDay.values filter isWorkingDay foreach println
  }
```

Comment: Seriously, Application should not be used.  It was NOT fixed; a new class, App, was introduced, which does not have the problems Schildmeijer mentioned.  So do "object foo extends App { ... }"  And you have immediate access to command-line arguments through the args variable.

Comment: scala.Enumeration (which is what you are using in your "object WeekDay" code sample above) does not offer exhaustive pattern matching. I have researched all the different enumeration patterns currently being used in Scala and give and overview of them in this StackOverflow answer (including a new pattern which  offers the best of both scala.Enumeration and the "sealed trait + case object" pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25923651/501113

Answer (score 375):

I must say that the example *copied out of the Scala documentation* by *skaffman* above is of limited utility in practice (you might as well use `case object`s).

In order to get something most closely resembling a Java `Enum` (i.e. with sensible `toString` and `valueOf` methods  -- perhaps you are persisting the enum values to a database) you need to modify it a bit. If you had used *skaffman*'s code:

```
WeekDay.valueOf("Sun") //returns None
WeekDay.Tue.toString   //returns Weekday(2)
```

Whereas using the following declaration:

```
object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
  type WeekDay = Value
  val Mon = Value("Mon")
  val Tue = Value("Tue") 
  ... etc
}
```

You get more sensible results:

```
WeekDay.valueOf("Sun") //returns Some(Sun)
WeekDay.Tue.toString   //returns Tue
```

Comment: Btw. valueOf method is now dead :-(

Comment: @macias `valueOf`'s replacement is `withName`, which doesn't return an Option, and throws a NSE if there is no match. What the!

Comment: @Bluu You can add valueOf yourself:   
def valueOf(name: String) = WeekDay.values.find(_.toString == name) to have an Option

Comment: @centr When I try to create a `Map[Weekday.Weekday, Long]` and add a value say `Mon` to it the compiler throws an invalid type error. Expected Weekday.Weekday found Value? Why does this happen?

Comment: @Sohaib It should be Map[Weekday.Value, Long].

Comment: @centr But Weekday is just an alias for Value ?

Comment: My IDE gives me a warning Type annotation required for public member. Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 99):

There are many ways of doing.

1) Use symbols. It won't give you any type safety, though, aside from not accepting non-symbols where a symbol is expected. I'm only mentioning it here for completeness. Here's an example of usage:

```
def update(what: Symbol, where: Int, newValue: Array[Int]): MatrixInt =
  what match {
    case 'row => replaceRow(where, newValue)
    case 'col | 'column => replaceCol(where, newValue)
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
  }

// At REPL:   
scala> val a = unitMatrixInt(3)
a: teste7.MatrixInt =
/ 1 0 0 \
| 0 1 0 |
\ 0 0 1 /

scala> a('row, 1) = a.row(0)
res41: teste7.MatrixInt =
/ 1 0 0 \
| 1 0 0 |
\ 0 0 1 /

scala> a('column, 2) = a.row(0)
res42: teste7.MatrixInt =
/ 1 0 1 \
| 0 1 0 |
\ 0 0 0 /
```

2) Using class `Enumeration`:

```
object Dimension extends Enumeration {
  type Dimension = Value
  val Row, Column = Value
}
```

or, if you need to serialize or display it:

```
object Dimension extends Enumeration("Row", "Column") {
  type Dimension = Value
  val Row, Column = Value
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
def update(what: Dimension, where: Int, newValue: Array[Int]): MatrixInt =
  what match {
    case Row => replaceRow(where, newValue)
    case Column => replaceCol(where, newValue)
  }

// At REPL:
scala> a(Row, 2) = a.row(1)
<console>:13: error: not found: value Row
       a(Row, 2) = a.row(1)
         ^

scala> a(Dimension.Row, 2) = a.row(1)
res1: teste.MatrixInt =
/ 1 0 0 \
| 0 1 0 |
\ 0 1 0 /

scala> import Dimension._
import Dimension._

scala> a(Row, 2) = a.row(1)
res2: teste.MatrixInt =
/ 1 0 0 \
| 0 1 0 |
\ 0 1 0 /
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't ensure that all matches are accounted for. If I forgot to put Row or Column in the match, the Scala compiler wouldn't have warned me. So it gives me *some* type safety, but not as much as can be gained.

3) Case objects:

```
sealed abstract class Dimension
case object Row extends Dimension
case object Column extends Dimension
```

Now, if I leave out a case on a `match`, the compiler will warn me:

```
MatrixInt.scala:70: warning: match is not exhaustive!
missing combination         Column

    what match {
    ^
one warning found
```

It's used pretty much the same way, and doesn't even need an `import`:

```
scala> val a = unitMatrixInt(3)
a: teste3.MatrixInt =
/ 1 0 0 \
| 0 1 0 |
\ 0 0 1 /

scala> a(Row,2) = a.row(0)
res15: teste3.MatrixInt =
/ 1 0 0 \
| 0 1 0 |
\ 1 0 0 /
```

You might wonder, then, why ever use an Enumeration instead of case objects. As a matter of fact, case objects do have advantages many times, such as here. The Enumeration class, though, has many Collection methods, such as elements (iterator on Scala 2.8), which returns an Iterator, map, flatMap, filter, etc.

This answer is essentially a selected parts from [this article](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2009/06/matrices-4.html) in my blog.

Comment: "... not accepting non-symbols where a symbol is expected" > I'm guessing you mean that `Symbol` instances cannot have spaces or special characters. Most people when first encountering the `Symbol` class probably think so, but is actually incorrect. `Symbol("foo !% bar -* baz")` compiles and run perfectly fine. In other words you can perfectly create `Symbol` instances wrapping *any* string (you just cannot do it with the "single coma" syntactic sugar). The only thing that `Symbol` does guarantee is the uniqueness of any given symbol, making it marginally faster to compare and match over.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles No, I mean that you cannot pass a `String`, for example, as argument to a `Symbol` parameter.

Comment: Yes, I understood that part, but it's a pretty moot point if you replace `String` with another class that is basically a wrapper around a string and can be freely converted in both directions (as is the case for `Symbol`). I guess that's what you meant when saying "It won't give you any type safety", it just wasn't very clear given that OP explicitly asked for type safe solutions. I wasn't sure if at the time of writing you knew that not only is it not type safe because those are not enums at all, but **also** `Symbol`s don't even guarantee that the passed argument won't have special chars.

Comment: To elaborate, when you say "not accepting non-symbols where a symbol is expected", it can be read either as "not accepting values that are not instances of Symbol" (which is obviously true) or "not accepting values that are not plain identifier-like strings, aka 'symbols'" (which is not true, and is a misconception that pretty much anybody has the first time we encounter scala symbols, due to the fact that the first encounter is though the special `'foo` notation which **does** preclude non-identifier strings). This is this misconception that I wanted to dispel for any future reader.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles I meant the former, the one which is obviously true. I mean, it's obviously true for anyone used to static typing. Back then there was a lot of discussion on the relative merits of static and "dynamic" typing, and a lot of people interested in Scala came from a dynamic typing background, so it I thought it _didn't_ go without saying. I wouldn't even think of making that remark nowadays. Personally, I think Scala's Symbol is ugly and redundant, and never use it. I'm upvoting your last comment, since it's a good point.

Comment: "I think Scala's Symbol is ugly and redundant" > oh I could not agree more on that one. And we seem to be in good company as it appears that it's going away in scala 3.

Answer (score 53):

A slightly less verbose way of declaring named enumerations:

```
object WeekDay extends Enumeration("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat") {
  type WeekDay = Value
  val Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat = Value
}

WeekDay.valueOf("Wed") // returns Some(Wed)
WeekDay.Fri.toString   // returns Fri
```

Of course the problem here is that you will need to keep the ordering of the names and vals in sync which is easier to do if name and val are declared on the same line.

Comment: This looks cleaner at first glance, but has the disadvantage of requiring the maintainer to keep the oder of both lists in sync. For the days of week example, it doesn't appear likely. But in general, the a new value could be inserted, or one deleted and the two lists could be out of sync, in which case, subtle bugs could be introduced.

Comment: Per the prior comment, the risk is the two different lists can silently go out of sync. While it’s not an issue for your current small example, if there are many more members (like in the dozens to hundreds), the odds of the two lists silently going out of sync is substantially higher. Also scala.Enumeration cannot benefit from Scala's compile time exhaustive pattern matching warnings/errors. I’ve created a StackOverflow answer which contains a solution performing a runtime check to ensure the two lists remain in sync: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25923651/501113

Answer (score 18):

You can use a sealed abstract class instead of the enumeration, for example:

```
sealed abstract class Constraint(val name: String, val verifier: Int => Boolean)

case object NotTooBig extends Constraint("NotTooBig", (_ < 1000))
case object NonZero extends Constraint("NonZero", (_ != 0))
case class NotEquals(x: Int) extends Constraint("NotEquals " + x, (_ != x))

object Main {

  def eval(ctrs: Seq[Constraint])(x: Int): Boolean =
    (true /: ctrs){ case (accum, ctr) => accum && ctr.verifier(x) }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val ctrs = NotTooBig :: NotEquals(5) :: Nil
    val evaluate = eval(ctrs) _

    println(evaluate(3000))
    println(evaluate(3))
    println(evaluate(5))
  }

}
```

Comment: Sealed trait with case objects is also a possibility.

Comment: The "sealed trait + case objects" pattern has issues which I detail in a StackOverflow answer. However, I did figure out how to resolve all the issues related to this pattern which is also covered in the thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25923651/501113

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Scala 3, there is now [enum keyword](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/enums/enums.html) which can represent a set of constants (and other use cases)

```
enum Color:
   case Red, Green, Blue

scala> val red = Color.Red
val red: Color = Red
scala> red.ordinal
val res0: Int = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In Scala it is very comfortable with https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum

Project is really good with examples and documentation

Just this example from their docs should makes you interested in

```
import enumeratum._

sealed trait Greeting extends EnumEntry

object Greeting extends Enum[Greeting] {

  /*
   `findValues` is a protected method that invokes a macro to find all `Greeting` object declarations inside an `Enum`

   You use it to implement the `val values` member
  */
  val values = findValues

  case object Hello   extends Greeting
  case object GoodBye extends Greeting
  case object Hi      extends Greeting
  case object Bye     extends Greeting

}

// Object Greeting has a `withName(name: String)` method
Greeting.withName("Hello")
// => res0: Greeting = Hello

Greeting.withName("Haro")
// => java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Haro is not a member of Enum (Hello, GoodBye, Hi, Bye)

// A safer alternative would be to use `withNameOption(name: String)` method which returns an Option[Greeting]
Greeting.withNameOption("Hello")
// => res1: Option[Greeting] = Some(Hello)

Greeting.withNameOption("Haro")
// => res2: Option[Greeting] = None

// It is also possible to use strings case insensitively
Greeting.withNameInsensitive("HeLLo")
// => res3: Greeting = Hello

Greeting.withNameInsensitiveOption("HeLLo")
// => res4: Option[Greeting] = Some(Hello)

// Uppercase-only strings may also be used
Greeting.withNameUppercaseOnly("HELLO")
// => res5: Greeting = Hello

Greeting.withNameUppercaseOnlyOption("HeLLo")
// => res6: Option[Greeting] = None

// Similarly, lowercase-only strings may also be used
Greeting.withNameLowercaseOnly("hello")
// => res7: Greeting = Hello

Greeting.withNameLowercaseOnlyOption("hello")
// => res8: Option[Greeting] = Some(Hello)
```