# Case objects vs Enumerations in Scala

Tags: scala, enumeration, case-class

Are there any best-practice guidelines on when to use [case classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29#Case_classes_and_pattern_matching) (or case objects) vs extending Enumeration in Scala?

They seem to offer some of the same benefits.

Comment: I've written a small overview about scala Enumeration and alternatives, you may find it useful: pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-enums/

Comment: See also the [Dotty-based Scala 3 `enum`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56566369/6309) (for mid 2020).

Comment: If using Scala 2.X, please use this standardized implementation managed by Typelevel: https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum

Answer (score 239, accepted):

One big difference is that `Enumeration`s come with support for instantiating them from some `name` String. For example:

```
object Currency extends Enumeration {
   val GBP = Value("GBP")
   val EUR = Value("EUR") //etc.
}
```

Then you can do:

```
val ccy = Currency.withName("EUR")
```

This is useful when wishing to persist enumerations (for example, to a database) or create them from data residing in files. However, I find in general that enumerations are a bit clumsy in Scala and have the feel of an awkward add-on, so I now tend to use `case object`s. A `case object` is more flexible than an enum:

```
sealed trait Currency { def name: String }
case object EUR extends Currency { val name = "EUR" } //etc.

case class UnknownCurrency(name: String) extends Currency
```

So now I have the advantage of...

```
trade.ccy match {
  case EUR                   =>
  case UnknownCurrency(code) =>
}
```

As [@chaotic3quilibrium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501113/chaotic3quilibrium) pointed out (with some corrections to ease reading):

> Regarding "UnknownCurrency(code)" pattern, there are other ways to handle not finding a currency code string than "breaking" the closed set nature of the `Currency` type. `UnknownCurrency` being of type `Currency` can now sneak into other parts of an API.
>
> It's advisable to push that case outside `Enumeration` and make the client deal with an `Option[Currency]` type that would clearly indicate there is really a matching problem and "encourage" the user of the API to sort it out him/herself.

To follow up on the other answers here, the main drawbacks of `case object`s over `Enumeration`s are:

1. *Can't iterate over all instances of the "enumeration"*. This is certainly the case, but I've found it extremely rare in practice that this is required.
2. *Can't instantiate easily from persisted value*. This is also true but, except in the case of huge enumerations (for example, all currencies), this doesn't present a huge overhead.

Comment: The other difference is that Enumeration enum is ordered out of the box, whereas case object based enum obviosly not

Comment: Another point for case objects is if you care about java interoperability. The Enumeration would return the values as Enumeration.Value, thus 1) requiring scala-library, 2) losing the actual type information.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes Regarding point 1, specifically this part "...I've found it extremely rare in practice that this is required": Apparently you rarely do much UI work. This is an extremely common use case; displaying a (drop-down) list of valid enumeration members from which to pick.

Comment: I don't understand the type of the item being matched `trade.ccy` in the sealed trait exemple.

Comment: and don't `case` `object`s generate bigger (~4x) code footprint than `Enumeration`? Useful distinction especially for `scala.js` projects needing small footprint.

Answer (score 73):

**UPDATE:**
A new [macro based solution](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum) has been created which is far superior to the solution I outline below. I strongly recommend using this new [macro based solution](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum). [And it appears plans for Dotty will make this style of enum solution part of the language.](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/1970) Whoohoo!

**Summary:**
There are three basic patterns for attempting to reproduce the Java `Enum` within a Scala project. Two of the three patterns; directly using Java `Enum` and `scala.Enumeration`, are not capable of enabling Scala's exhaustive pattern matching. And the third one; "sealed trait + case object", does...but has [JVM class/object initialization complications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14947179/501113) resulting in inconsistent ordinal index generation.

I have created a solution with two classes; [Enumeration](https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/57add1cd762eb90f6b24#file-org-public_domain-scala-utils-enumeration-scala) and [EnumerationDecorated](https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/57add1cd762eb90f6b24#file-org-public_domain-scala-utils-enumerationdecorated-scala), located in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/57add1cd762eb90f6b24). I didn't post the code into this thread as the file for Enumeration was quite large (+400 lines - contains lots of comments explaining implementation context).


**Details:**
The question you're asking is pretty general; "...when to use `case`<s>classes</s>`objects` vs extending `[scala.]Enumeration`". And it turns out there are MANY possible answers, each answer depending on the subtleties of the specific project requirements you have. The answer can be reduced down to three basic patterns.

To start, let's make sure we are working from the same basic idea of what an enumeration is. Let's define an enumeration mostly in terms of the [`Enum` provided as of Java 5 (1.5)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html):

1. It contains a naturally ordered closed set of named members

   1. There is a fixed number of members
   2. Members are naturally ordered and explicitly indexed

      - As opposed to being sorted based on some inate member queriable criteria
   3. Each member has a unique name within the total set of all members
2. All members can easily be iterated through based on their indexes
3. A member can be retrieved with its (case sensitive) name

   1. It would be quite nice if a member could also be retrieved with its case insensitive name
4. A member can be retrieved with its index
5. Members may easily, transparently and efficiently use serialization
6. Members may be easily extended to hold additional associated singleton-ness data
7. Thinking beyond Java's `Enum`, it would be nice to be able to explicitly leverage Scala's pattern matching exhaustiveness checking for an enumeration

Next, let's look at boiled down versions of the three most common solution patterns posted:


**A)** Actually directly using **Java `Enum`** pattern (in a mixed Scala/Java project):

```
public enum ChessPiece {
    KING('K', 0)
  , QUEEN('Q', 9)
  , BISHOP('B', 3)
  , KNIGHT('N', 3)
  , ROOK('R', 5)
  , PAWN('P', 1)
  ;

  private char character;
  private int pointValue;

  private ChessPiece(char character, int pointValue) {
    this.character = character; 
    this.pointValue = pointValue;   
  }

  public int getCharacter() {
    return character;
  }

  public int getPointValue() {
    return pointValue;
  }
}
```

The following items from the enumeration definition are not available:

1. 3.1 - It would be quite nice if a member could also be retrieved with its case insensitive name
2. 7 - Thinking beyond Java's Enum, it would be nice to be able to explicitly leverage Scala's pattern matching exhaustiveness checking for an enumeration

For my current projects, I don't have the benefit of taking the risks around the Scala/Java mixed project pathway. And even if I could choose to do a mixed project, item 7 is critical for allowing me to catch compile time issues if/when I either add/remove enumeration members, or am writing some new code to deal with existing enumeration members.


**B)** Using the "**`sealed trait` + `case objects`**" pattern:

```
sealed trait ChessPiece {def character: Char; def pointValue: Int}
object ChessPiece {
  case object KING extends ChessPiece {val character = 'K'; val pointValue = 0}
  case object QUEEN extends ChessPiece {val character = 'Q'; val pointValue = 9}
  case object BISHOP extends ChessPiece {val character = 'B'; val pointValue = 3}
  case object KNIGHT extends ChessPiece {val character = 'N'; val pointValue = 3}
  case object ROOK extends ChessPiece {val character = 'R'; val pointValue = 5}
  case object PAWN extends ChessPiece {val character = 'P'; val pointValue = 1}
}
```

The following items from the enumeration definition are not available:

1. 1.2 - Members are naturally ordered and explicitly indexed
2. 2 - All members can easily be iterated through based on their indexes
3. 3 - A member can be retrieved with its (case sensitive) name
4. 3.1 - It would be quite nice if a member could also be retrieved with its case insensitive name
5. 4 - A member can be retrieved with its index

It's arguable it really meets enumeration definition items 5 and 6. For 5, it's a stretch to claim it's efficient. For 6, it's not really easy to extend to hold additional associated singleton-ness data.


**C)** Using the **`scala.Enumeration`** pattern (inspired by [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24840925/501113)):

```
object ChessPiece extends Enumeration {
  val KING = ChessPieceVal('K', 0)
  val QUEEN = ChessPieceVal('Q', 9)
  val BISHOP = ChessPieceVal('B', 3)
  val KNIGHT = ChessPieceVal('N', 3)
  val ROOK = ChessPieceVal('R', 5)
  val PAWN = ChessPieceVal('P', 1)
  protected case class ChessPieceVal(character: Char, pointValue: Int) extends super.Val()
  implicit def convert(value: Value) = value.asInstanceOf[ChessPieceVal]
}
```

The following items from the enumeration definition are not available (happens to be identical to the list for directly using the Java Enum):

1. 3.1 - It would be quite nice if a member could also be retrieved with its case insensitive name
2. 7 - Thinking beyond Java's Enum, it would be nice to be able to explicitly leverage Scala's pattern matching exhaustiveness checking for an enumeration

Again for my current projects, item 7 is critical for allowing me to catch compile time issues if/when I either add/remove enumeration members, or am writing some new code to deal with existing enumeration members.

---

So, given the above definition of an enumeration, none of the above three solutions work as they do not provide everything outlined in the enumeration definition above:

1. Java Enum directly in a mixed Scala/Java project
2. "sealed trait + case objects"
3. scala.Enumeration

Each of these solutions can be eventually reworked/expanded/refactored to attempt to cover some of each one's missing requirements. However, neither the Java `Enum` nor the `scala.Enumeration` solutions can be sufficiently expanded to provide item 7. And for my own projects, this is one of the more compelling values of using a closed type within Scala. I strongly prefer compile time warnings/errors to indicate I have a gap/issue in my code as opposed to having to glean it out of a production runtime exception/failure.

---

In that regard, I set about working with the `case object` pathway to see if I could produce a solution which covered all of the enumeration definition above. The first challenge was to push through the core of the JVM class/object initialization issue (covered in detail in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14947179/501113)). And I was finally able to figure out a solution.

As my solution is two traits; [Enumeration](https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/57add1cd762eb90f6b24#file-org-public_domain-scala-utils-enumeration-scala) and [EnumerationDecorated](https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/57add1cd762eb90f6b24#file-org-public_domain-scala-utils-enumerationdecorated-scala), and since the `Enumeration` trait is over +400 lines long (lots of comments explaining context), I am forgoing pasting it into this thread (which would make it stretch down the page considerbly). For details, please jump directly to the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/57add1cd762eb90f6b24).

Here's what the solution ends up looking like using the same data idea as above (fully commented version [available here](https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/57add1cd762eb90f6b24#file-org-public_domain-chess-chesspiecesenhanceddecorated-scala)) and implemented in `EnumerationDecorated`.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag,typeTag}
import org.public_domain.scala.utils.EnumerationDecorated

object ChessPiecesEnhancedDecorated extends EnumerationDecorated {
  case object KING extends Member
  case object QUEEN extends Member
  case object BISHOP extends Member
  case object KNIGHT extends Member
  case object ROOK extends Member
  case object PAWN extends Member

  val decorationOrderedSet: List[Decoration] =
    List(
        Decoration(KING,   'K', 0)
      , Decoration(QUEEN,  'Q', 9)
      , Decoration(BISHOP, 'B', 3)
      , Decoration(KNIGHT, 'N', 3)
      , Decoration(ROOK,   'R', 5)
      , Decoration(PAWN,   'P', 1)
    )

  final case class Decoration private[ChessPiecesEnhancedDecorated] (member: Member, char: Char, pointValue: Int) extends DecorationBase {
    val description: String = member.name.toLowerCase.capitalize
  }
  override def typeTagMember: TypeTag[_] = typeTag[Member]
  sealed trait Member extends MemberDecorated
}
```

This is an example usage of a new pair of enumeration traits I created (located in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/57add1cd762eb90f6b24)) to implement all of the capabilities desired and outlined in the enumeration definition.

One concern expressed is that the enumeration member names must be repeated (`decorationOrderedSet` in the example above). While I did minimize it down to a single repetition, I couldn't see how to make it even less due to two issues:

1. JVM object/class initialization for this particular object/case object model is undefined (see [this Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947179/using-a-custom-enum-in-the-scala-worksheet-i-am-receiving-an-error-java-lang-ex))
2. The content returned from the method `getClass.getDeclaredClasses` has an undefined order (and it is quite unlikely to be in the same order as the `case object` declarations in the source code)

Given these two issues, I had to give up trying to generate an implied ordering and had to explicitly require the client define and declare it with some sort of ordered set notion. As the Scala collections do not have an insert ordered set implementation, the best I could do was use a `List` and then runtime check that it was truly a set. It's not how I would have preferred to have achieved this.

And given the design required this second list/set ordering `val`, given the `ChessPiecesEnhancedDecorated` example above, it was possible to add `case object PAWN2 extends Member` and then forget to add `Decoration(PAWN2,'P2', 2)` to `decorationOrderedSet`. So, there is a runtime check to verify that the list is not only a set, but contains ALL of the case objects which extend the `sealed trait Member`. That was a special form of reflection/macro hell to work through.


Please leave comments and/or feedback on the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/57add1cd762eb90f6b24).

Comment: I have now released the first version of the ScalaOlio library (GPLv3) which contains more up-to-date versions of both `org.scalaolio.util.Enumeration` and `org.scalaolio.util.EnumerationDecorated`: http://scalaolio.org/

Comment: And to hop directly to the ScalaOlio repository on Github: https://github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/scala-olio

Comment: This is a quality answer and a lot to take from it. Thank you

Comment: It looks like Odersky is wanting to upgrade Dotty (future Scala 3.0) with a native enum. Whoohoo! https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/1970

Answer (score 62):

Case objects already return their name for their toString methods, so passing it in separately is unnecessary.  Here is a version similar to jho's (convenience methods omitted for brevity):

```
trait Enum[A] {
  trait Value { self: A => }
  val values: List[A]
}

sealed trait Currency extends Currency.Value
object Currency extends Enum[Currency] {
  case object EUR extends Currency
  case object GBP extends Currency
  val values = List(EUR, GBP)
}
```

Objects are lazy; by using vals instead we can drop the list but have to repeat the name:

```
trait Enum[A <: {def name: String}] {
  trait Value { self: A =>
    _values :+= this
  }
  private var _values = List.empty[A]
  def values = _values
}

sealed abstract class Currency(val name: String) extends Currency.Value
object Currency extends Enum[Currency] {
  val EUR = new Currency("EUR") {}
  val GBP = new Currency("GBP") {}
}
```

If you don't mind some cheating, you can pre-load your enumeration values using the reflection API or something like Google Reflections.  Non-lazy case objects give you the cleanest syntax:

```
trait Enum[A] {
  trait Value { self: A =>
    _values :+= this
  }
  private var _values = List.empty[A]
  def values = _values
}

sealed trait Currency extends Currency.Value
object Currency extends Enum[Currency] {
  case object EUR extends Currency
  case object GBP extends Currency
}
```

Nice and clean, with all the advantages of case classes and Java enumerations.  Personally, I define the enumeration values outside of the object to better match idiomatic Scala code:

```
object Currency extends Enum[Currency]
sealed trait Currency extends Currency.Value
case object EUR extends Currency
case object GBP extends Currency
```

Comment: one question : the last solution is called "non lazy case objects" but in this case objects aren't be loaded until we use them : why do you call this solution non lazy ?

Comment: I'm dense, but copying any of these 3 examples into the repl chokes on the `sealed trait Currency extends Currency.Value` line, givng an `:5: error: not found: value Currency`

What am I missing?

Comment: @Noel, you need to use :paste to paste the whole sealed hierarchy into the REPL. If you don't, the single line with the sealed base class/trait counts as a single file, is sealed immediately, and cannot be extended on the next line.

Comment: @GatesDA Your trait Enum[A] solution (second to last code block) has a subtle bug. If Currency.GBP is the very first thing a client accesses after the JVM instance has started, the content of Enum.values will be out of order; i.e. GBP will be first and EUR will be second. I explored this JVM class/object initialization issue extensively on this StackOverflow thread: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14947179/501113

Comment: @GatesDA Only your first code snippet doesn't have a bug (as you explicitly require the client to declare and define values. Both your second and third solutions have the subtle bug I described in my last comment (if the client happens to access Currency.GBP directly and first, the values List will "be out of order"). I have explored the Scala enumeration domain extensively and have covered it in detail in my answer to this same thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25923651/501113

Comment: Perhaps one of the drawbacks of this approach (compared to Java Enums anyway) is that when you type Currency<dot> in IDE it does not show available options.

Comment: Rather than using "sealed abstract class Currency" (or trait), I have found it more useful (in particular when serialising to JSON using Gson), to make it concrete and the contractor private - "sealed class Currency private (name: String)"...

Comment: As @SebCesbron mentioned, the case objects are lazy here. So if I call `Currency.values`, I only get back values I have previously accessed. Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 31):

The advantages of using case classes over Enumerations are:

- When using sealed case classes, the Scala compiler can tell if the match is fully specified e.g. when all possible matches are espoused in the matching declaration.  With enumerations, the Scala compiler cannot tell.
- Case classes naturally supports more fields than a Value based Enumeration which supports a name and ID.

The advantages of using Enumerations instead of case classes are:

- Enumerations will generally be a bit less code to write.
- Enumerations are a bit easier to understand for someone new to Scala since they are prevalent in other languages

So in general, if you just need a list of simple constants by name, use enumerations.  Otherwise, if you need something a bit more complex or want the extra safety of the compiler telling you if you have all matches specified, use case classes.

Answer (score 15):

UPDATE: The code below has a bug, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947179/using-a-custom-enum-in-the-scala-worksheet-i-am-receiving-an-error-java-lang-ex).  The test program below works, but if you were to use DayOfWeek.Mon (for example) before DayOfWeek itself, it would fail because DayOfWeek has not been initialized (use of an inner object does not cause an outer object to be initialized).  You can still use this code if you do something like `val enums = Seq( DayOfWeek )` in your main class, forcing initialization of your enums, or you can use chaotic3quilibrium's modifications.  Looking forward to a macro-based enum!

---

If you want

- warnings about non-exhaustive pattern matches
- an Int ID assigned to each enum value, which you can optionally control
- an immutable List of the enum values, in the order they were defined
- an immutable Map from name to enum value
- an immutable Map from id to enum value
- places to stick methods/data for all or particular enum values, or for the enum as a whole
- ordered enum values (so you can test, for example, whether day < Wednesday)
- the ability to extend one enum to create others

then the following may be of interest.  Feedback welcome.

In this implementation there are abstract Enum and EnumVal base classes, which you extend.  We'll see those classes in a minute, but first, here's how you would define an enum:

```
object DayOfWeek extends Enum {
  sealed abstract class Val extends EnumVal
  case object Mon extends Val; Mon()
  case object Tue extends Val; Tue()
  case object Wed extends Val; Wed()
  case object Thu extends Val; Thu()
  case object Fri extends Val; Fri()
  case object Sat extends Val; Sat()
  case object Sun extends Val; Sun()
}
```

Note that you have to use each enum value (call its apply method) to bring it to life.  [I wish inner objects weren't lazy unless I specifically ask for them to be.  I think.]

We could of course add methods/data to DayOfWeek, Val, or the individual case objects if we so desired.

And here's how you would use such an enum:

```
object DayOfWeekTest extends App {

  // To get a map from Int id to enum:
  println( DayOfWeek.valuesById )

  // To get a map from String name to enum:
  println( DayOfWeek.valuesByName )

  // To iterate through a list of the enum values in definition order,
  // which can be made different from ID order, and get their IDs and names:
  DayOfWeek.values foreach { v => println( v.id + " = " + v ) }

  // To sort by ID or name:
  println( DayOfWeek.values.sorted mkString ", " )
  println( DayOfWeek.values.sortBy(_.toString) mkString ", " )

  // To look up enum values by name:
  println( DayOfWeek("Tue") ) // Some[DayOfWeek.Val]
  println( DayOfWeek("Xyz") ) // None

  // To look up enum values by id:
  println( DayOfWeek(3) )         // Some[DayOfWeek.Val]
  println( DayOfWeek(9) )         // None

  import DayOfWeek._

  // To compare enums as ordinals:
  println( Tue < Fri )

  // Warnings about non-exhaustive pattern matches:
  def aufDeutsch( day: DayOfWeek.Val ) = day match {
    case Mon => "Montag"
    case Tue => "Dienstag"
    case Wed => "Mittwoch"
    case Thu => "Donnerstag"
    case Fri => "Freitag"
 // Commenting these out causes compiler warning: "match is not exhaustive!"
 // case Sat => "Samstag"
 // case Sun => "Sonntag"
  }

}
```

Here's what you get when you compile it:

```
DayOfWeekTest.scala:31: warning: match is not exhaustive!
missing combination            Sat
missing combination            Sun

  def aufDeutsch( day: DayOfWeek.Val ) = day match {
                                         ^
one warning found
```

You can replace "day match" with "( day: @unchecked ) match" where you don't want such warnings, or simply include a catch-all case at the end.

When you run the above program, you get this output:

```
Map(0 -> Mon, 5 -> Sat, 1 -> Tue, 6 -> Sun, 2 -> Wed, 3 -> Thu, 4 -> Fri)
Map(Thu -> Thu, Sat -> Sat, Tue -> Tue, Sun -> Sun, Mon -> Mon, Wed -> Wed, Fri -> Fri)
0 = Mon
1 = Tue
2 = Wed
3 = Thu
4 = Fri
5 = Sat
6 = Sun
Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun
Fri, Mon, Sat, Sun, Thu, Tue, Wed
Some(Tue)
None
Some(Thu)
None
true
```

Note that since the List and Maps are immutable, you can easily remove elements to create subsets, without breaking the enum itself.

Here is the Enum class itself (and EnumVal within it):

```
abstract class Enum {

  type Val <: EnumVal

  protected var nextId: Int = 0

  private var values_       =       List[Val]()
  private var valuesById_   = Map[Int   ,Val]()
  private var valuesByName_ = Map[String,Val]()

  def values       = values_
  def valuesById   = valuesById_
  def valuesByName = valuesByName_

  def apply( id  : Int    ) = valuesById  .get(id  )  // Some|None
  def apply( name: String ) = valuesByName.get(name)  // Some|None

  // Base class for enum values; it registers the value with the Enum.
  protected abstract class EnumVal extends Ordered[Val] {
    val theVal = this.asInstanceOf[Val]  // only extend EnumVal to Val
    val id = nextId
    def bumpId { nextId += 1 }
    def compare( that:Val ) = this.id - that.id
    def apply() {
      if ( valuesById_.get(id) != None )
        throw new Exception( "cannot init " + this + " enum value twice" )
      bumpId
      values_ ++= List(theVal)
      valuesById_   += ( id       -> theVal )
      valuesByName_ += ( toString -> theVal )
    }
  }

}
```

And here is a more advanced use of it which controls the IDs and adds data/methods to the Val abstraction and to the enum itself:

```
object DayOfWeek extends Enum {

  sealed abstract class Val( val isWeekday:Boolean = true ) extends EnumVal {
    def isWeekend = !isWeekday
    val abbrev = toString take 3
  }
  case object    Monday extends Val;    Monday()
  case object   Tuesday extends Val;   Tuesday()
  case object Wednesday extends Val; Wednesday()
  case object  Thursday extends Val;  Thursday()
  case object    Friday extends Val;    Friday()
  nextId = -2
  case object  Saturday extends Val(false); Saturday()
  case object    Sunday extends Val(false);   Sunday()

  val (weekDays,weekendDays) = values partition (_.isWeekday)
}
```

Comment: Tyvm for providing this. I really appreciate it. However, I am noticing that it is using "var" as opposed to val. And this is a borderline mortal sin in the FP world. So, is there a way to implement this such that there is no use of var? Just curious if this is some sort of FP type edge case and I am not understanding how your implementation is FP undesirable.

Comment: I probably can't help you.  It is fairly common in Scala to write classes which mutate internally but which are immutable to those using them.  In the above example, a user of DayOfWeek cannot mutate the enum; there is no way, for example, to change the ID of Tuesday, or its name, after the fact.  But if you want an implementation which is free of mutation *internally*, then I've got nothing.  I wouldn't be surprised, though, to see a nice new enum facility based on macros in 2.11; ideas are being kicked around on scala-lang.

Comment: I'm getting a weird error in Scala Worksheet. If I directly use one of the Value instances, I get an initialization error. However, if I make a call to the .values method to see the contents of the enumeration, that works and then directly using the value instance works. Any idea what the initialization error is? And what the optimal way is to ensure the initialization occurs in the proper order regardless of calling convention?

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium: Wow!  Thank you for pursuing this, and of course thanks to Rex Kerr for the heavy lifting.  I'll mention the problem here and refer to the question you created.

Comment: "[Using `var`] is a borderline mortal sin in the FP world"—I don't think that opinion is universally accepted.

Comment: @AmigoNico Per the "UPDATE - 2014/Sep/17" above, I have finally solved the "id ordering problem" which occurs when the client inadvertently hits a case object spawning the JVM class/object initialization ordering issue. It is located at the following Gist: https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/57add1cd762eb90f6b24

Comment: I've now posted an answer to this same thread elaborating on the many enumeration patterns available in Scala: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25923651/501113

Answer (score 13):

I have a nice simple lib here that allows you to use sealed traits/classes as enum values without having to maintain your own list of values. It relies on a simple macro that is not dependent on the buggy `knownDirectSubclasses`.

https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum

Comment: Without a doubt, for Scala 2.X, this is absolutely the right solution. Tysvm for producing it. For Scala 3 (Dotty), it will come with a full native Enum implementation.

Answer (score 10):

Update March 2017: as commented by [Anthony Accioly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/664577/anthony-accioly), the `scala.Enumeration/enum` PR has been closed.

**[Dotty](http://dotty.epfl.ch/)** (next generation compiler for Scala) will take the lead, though [dotty issue 1970](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/1970) and [Martin Odersky's PR 1958](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/1958).

---

Note: there is now (August 2016, 6+ years later) a proposal to remove `scala.Enumeration`: [PR 5352](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5352)

> ### Deprecate `scala.Enumeration`, add `@enum` annotation
>
> The syntax

```
@enum
 class Toggle {
  ON
  OFF
 }
```

> is a possible implementation example, intention is to also support ADTs that conform to certain restrictions (no nesting, recursion or varying constructor parameters), e. g.:

```
@enum
sealed trait Toggle
case object ON  extends Toggle
case object OFF extends Toggle
```

> Deprecates the unmitigated disaster that is `scala.Enumeration`.
>
> #### Advantages of @enum over scala.Enumeration:
>
> - Actually works
> - Java interop
> - No erasure issues
> - No confusing mini-DSL to learn when defining enumerations
>
> #### Disadvantages: None.
>
> This addresses the issue of not being able to have one codebase that
>   supports Scala-JVM, `Scala.js` and Scala-Native (Java source code not supported on `Scala.js/Scala-Native`, Scala source code not able to define enums that are accepted by existing APIs on Scala-JVM).

Comment: The PR above has closed (no joy). It is now 2017 and looks like Dotty is finally going to get a enum construct. Here's the [issue](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/1970) and [Martin's PR](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/1958). Merge, merge, merge!

Answer (score 8):

Another disadvantage of case classes versus Enumerations when you will need to iterate or filter across all instances. This is a built-in capability of Enumeration (and Java enums as well) while case classes don't automatically support such capability.

In other words: "there's no easy way to get a list of the total set of enumerated values with case classes".

Answer (score 6):

If you are serious about maintaining interoperability with other JVM languages (e.g. Java) then the best option is to write Java enums.  Those work transparently from both Scala and Java code, which is more than can be said for `scala.Enumeration` or case objects.  Let's not have a new enumerations library for every new hobby project on GitHub, if it can be avoided!

Answer (score 4):

I've seen various versions of making a case class mimic an enumeration.  Here is my version:

```
trait CaseEnumValue {
    def name:String
}

trait CaseEnum {
    type V <: CaseEnumValue
    def values:List[V]
    def unapply(name:String):Option[String] = {
        if (values.exists(_.name == name)) Some(name) else None
    }
    def unapply(value:V):String = {
        return value.name
    }
    def apply(name:String):Option[V] = {
        values.find(_.name == name)
    }
}
```

Which allows you to construct case classes that look like the following:

```
abstract class Currency(override name:String) extends CaseEnumValue {
}

object Currency extends CaseEnum {
    type V = Site
    case object EUR extends Currency("EUR")
    case object GBP extends Currency("GBP")
    var values = List(EUR, GBP)
}
```

Maybe someone could come up with a better trick than simply adding a each case class to the list like I did.  This was all I could come up with at the time.

Comment: Why two separate unapply methods tho?

Comment: @jho I've been trying to work through your solution as-is, but it won't compile. In the second code snippit, there is a reference to Site in "type V = Site". I am not sure to what that is referring to clear up the compilation error. Next, why are you providing the empty braces for "abstract class Currency"? Couldn't they just be left off? Finally, why are you using a var in "var values = ..."? Doesn't this mean that clients could at any time from anywhere in the code assign a new List to values? Wouldn't it be far preferable to make it a val instead of a var?

Answer (score 3):

I prefer `case objects` (it's a matter of personal preference). To cope with the problems inherent to that approach (parse string and iterate over all elements), I've added a few lines that are not perfect, but are effective.

I'm pasting you the code here expecting it could be useful, and also that others could improve it.

```
/**
 * Enum for Genre. It contains the type, objects, elements set and parse method.
 *
 * This approach supports:
 *
 * - Pattern matching
 * - Parse from name
 * - Get all elements
 */
object Genre {
  sealed trait Genre

  case object MALE extends Genre
  case object FEMALE extends Genre

  val elements = Set (MALE, FEMALE) // You have to take care this set matches all objects

  def apply (code: String) =
    if (MALE.toString == code) MALE
    else if (FEMALE.toString == code) FEMALE
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException
}

/**
 * Enum usage (and tests).
 */
object GenreTest extends App {
  import Genre._

  val m1 = MALE
  val m2 = Genre ("MALE")

  assert (m1 == m2)
  assert (m1.toString == "MALE")

  val f1 = FEMALE
  val f2 = Genre ("FEMALE")

  assert (f1 == f2)
  assert (f1.toString == "FEMALE")

  try {
    Genre (null)
    assert (false)
  }
  catch {
    case e: IllegalArgumentException => assert (true)
  }

  try {
    Genre ("male")
    assert (false)
  }
  catch {
    case e: IllegalArgumentException => assert (true)
  }

  Genre.elements.foreach { println }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been going back and forth on these two options the last few times I've needed them.  Up until recently, my preference has been for the sealed trait/case object option.

1) Scala Enumeration Declaration

```
object OutboundMarketMakerEntryPointType extends Enumeration {
  type OutboundMarketMakerEntryPointType = Value

  val Alpha, Beta = Value
}
```

2) Sealed Traits + Case Objects

```
sealed trait OutboundMarketMakerEntryPointType

case object AlphaEntryPoint extends OutboundMarketMakerEntryPointType

case object BetaEntryPoint extends OutboundMarketMakerEntryPointType
```

While neither of these really meet all of what a java enumeration gives you, below are the pros and cons:

Scala Enumeration

Pros:
-Functions for instantiating with option or directly assuming accurate (easier when loading from a persistent store)
-Iteration over all possible values is supported

Cons:
-Compilation warning for non-exhaustive search is not supported (makes pattern matching less ideal)

Case Objects/Sealed traits

Pros:
-Using sealed traits, we can pre-instantiate some values while others can be injected at creation time
-full support for pattern matching (apply/unapply methods defined)

Cons:
-Instantiating from a persistent store - you often have to use pattern matching here or define your own list of all possible 'enum values'

What ultimately made me change my opinion was something like the following snippet:

```
object DbInstrumentQueries {
  def instrumentExtractor(tableAlias: String = "s")(rs: ResultSet): Instrument = {
    val symbol = rs.getString(tableAlias + ".name")
    val quoteCurrency = rs.getString(tableAlias + ".quote_currency")
    val fixRepresentation = rs.getString(tableAlias + ".fix_representation")
    val pointsValue = rs.getInt(tableAlias + ".points_value")
    val instrumentType = InstrumentType.fromString(rs.getString(tableAlias +".instrument_type"))
    val productType = ProductType.fromString(rs.getString(tableAlias + ".product_type"))

    Instrument(symbol, fixRepresentation, quoteCurrency, pointsValue, instrumentType, productType)
  }
}

object InstrumentType {
  def fromString(instrumentType: String): InstrumentType = Seq(CurrencyPair, Metal, CFD)
  .find(_.toString == instrumentType).get
}

object ProductType {

  def fromString(productType: String): ProductType = Seq(Commodity, Currency, Index)
  .find(_.toString == productType).get
}
```

The `.get` calls were hideous - using enumeration instead I can simply call the withName method on the enumeration as follows:

```
object DbInstrumentQueries {
  def instrumentExtractor(tableAlias: String = "s")(rs: ResultSet): Instrument = {
    val symbol = rs.getString(tableAlias + ".name")
    val quoteCurrency = rs.getString(tableAlias + ".quote_currency")
    val fixRepresentation = rs.getString(tableAlias + ".fix_representation")
    val pointsValue = rs.getInt(tableAlias + ".points_value")
    val instrumentType = InstrumentType.withNameString(rs.getString(tableAlias + ".instrument_type"))
    val productType = ProductType.withName(rs.getString(tableAlias + ".product_type"))

    Instrument(symbol, fixRepresentation, quoteCurrency, pointsValue, instrumentType, productType)
  }
}
```

So I think my preference going forward is to use Enumerations when the values are intended to be accessed from a repository and case objects/sealed traits otherwise.

Comment: I can see how the second code pattern is desirable (getting rid of the two helper methods from the first code pattern). However, I figured out a way such you are not forced to choose between these two patterns. I cover the entire domain in the answer I have posted to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25923651/501113

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking how to get [GatesDa's answer to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4958905/1535591):
You can just reference the case object after declaring it to instantiate it:

```
trait Enum[A] {
  trait Value { self: A =>
    _values :+= this
  }
  private var _values = List.empty[A]
  def values = _values
}

sealed trait Currency extends Currency.Value
object Currency extends Enum[Currency] {
  case object EUR extends Currency; 
  EUR //THIS IS ONLY CHANGE
  case object GBP extends Currency; GBP //Inline looks better
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest advantage of having `case classes` over `enumerations` is that you can use **[type class pattern](https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html)** a.k.a **ad-hoc polymorphysm**. Don't need to match enums like:

```
someEnum match {
  ENUMA => makeThis()
  ENUMB => makeThat()
}
```

instead you'll have something like:

```
def someCode[SomeCaseClass](implicit val maker: Maker[SomeCaseClass]){
  maker.make()
}

implicit val makerA = new Maker[CaseClassA]{
  def make() = ...
}
implicit val makerB = new Maker[CaseClassB]{
  def make() = ...
}
```