# What is the syntax for creating a Map in Scala that uses an enum as a key?

Tags: scala

please see the below code. This line is marked as incorrect by Eclipse:

```
var map = Map[MyEnum,Point]()
```

I am trying to do the scala equivalent of Java:

```
private enum Letters{ A,B,C}
private Map<Letters,Integer> thing= new HashMap<Letters,Integer> ();
```

And this is the file/context in which it is written.

```
class Point(var x:Int = 0, var y:Int = 0, var hasBeenSet:Boolean = false){

}

object MyEnum extends Enumeration{
    MyEnum = Value
    val UL,U,UR,L,R,DL,D,DR = Value
}

object MyEnumHolder {
  var map = Map[MyEnum,Point]()
  MyEnum.values.foreach(x => (map + (x -> new Point()) ) 
}
```

I am trying to initialize an instance of the map with each value of the enum mapped to an empty point (that's what is going on in the for each loop).

**EDIT: Had to edit because I messed some things up editing the pasted code, but it should be valid now**

Comment: I think you meant to write `type MyEnum = Value`

Comment: You are correct, I fixed it in an edit ;) Thanks!

Comment: An aside: `Enumeration` is broken beyond hope. Don't use it, unless you hate yourself and your fellow developers.

Comment: By the way: if you want to use `enum`s as keys in a Java map, you should probably use an `EnumMap`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var map = Map[MyEnum.Value, Point]()
```

or I prefer

```
import MyEnum._
var map = Map[MyEnum,Point]()
```

edit: To give a little explanation of what this means, in the enumeration `Value` is the name of both a type and a method.  `type MyEnum = Value` is basically just declaring an alias for the `Value` type, and the next line `val UL, U... = Value` is calling the method to generate the enums, each of which has type `MyEnum.Value`.  So when declaring the map, you have to refer to this type in order for the key to store enums.  You could also use `MyEnum.MyEnum`, but the reason you declare the type alias in the first place is so you can import it into scope and be able to refer to it just as `MyEnum`.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks! I don't understand the meaning of .Value though I think is my problem, will have to look that up.

Answer (score 2):

You are not putting `MyEnums` in the map, but *values* of `MyEnum`:

```
var map = Map[MyEnum.Value, Point]()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
  type MyEnum = Value /* You were missing keyword "type" here */
  val UL,U,UR,L,R,DL,D,DR = Value
}

object MyEnumHolder {
  import MyEnum.MyEnum /* Import this, otherwise type MyEnum can't be found */

  var map = Map[MyEnum, String]()
  MyEnum.values.foreach(x => (map + (x -> x.toString)))
}
```

You might also want to have a look at [Case classes vs Enumerations in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898932/case-classes-vs-enumerations-in-scala).

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with the following. The syntax is a bit wonky, I'll admit.

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
    type MyEnum = Value
    val UL, U, UR, L, R, DL, D, DR = Value
}

object Main extends App {
    Map[MyEnum.MyEnum, String]()

}
```

Although I guess it can help for pluralization

```
object Diaries extends Enumeration {
    type Diary = Value
    val Steven, Jessica, Bob = Value
}

import Diaries._

val currentDiary = Steven

val interestingDiaries = List[Diary](Steven, Jessica)
```

So here Diaries is the list of Diary, and Diary is a *specific* diary in the list.