# Enum as key to a mutable map in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, enums, mutablemap

I'm trying how to figure out *and work with* maps with enums as keys in Scala.  Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440497/what-is-the-syntax-for-creating-a-map-in-scala-that-uses-an-enum-as-a-key), I can instantiate maps, but when I try to update the map in place, I get a type mismatch error.  What is going on here?

```
object MyEnums extends Enumeration {
  type MyEnum = Value
  val BOB, TED, JEN = Value
}

var mymap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[MyEnums.Value, Long]()
mymap += (MyEnums.JEN -> 100L)
```

throws:

```
<console>:38: error: type mismatch;
found   : (MyEnums.Value, Long)
required: (MyEnums.Value, Long)
          mymap += (MyEnums.JEN -> 100L)
```

If I do the same thing, but use e.g. strings as the key type, this works as expected.

EDIT:  These issues occur when using scala in spark-shell, not the normal scala repl.

Comment: This works fine for me in a REPL. What scala version? An is there anything else in scope that you haven't shown us?

Comment: Huh weird, I was doing this using the spark shell (spark version 1.6.0, scala version 2.10.5).  When I tried this in regular scala repl, (scala version 2.11.7) it works as expected.  So is this just a bug that has been fixed?

Comment: Please consider removing or answering the question if it works correctly

Comment: Reproducible in spark-shell 1.6.0 scala 2.11.7. Probably it has something to do with custom classloader used in spark shell. For example, in [ammonium](https://github.com/alexarchambault/ammonium), a custom scala REPL  based on ammonite with spark support, OP's code works fine. I suggest to edit the question to make it clear that error is related to spark-shell.