# Is it possible to extend the Scala enumeration value type?

Tags: scala, enumeration

It would be great, if it is possible to extend the Scala enumeration value type in a way, that a kind of tree structure accrues. I mean something like that:

[Examples are just pseudo code!]

```
object SomeSubEnum extends Enumeration {
  type SomeSubEnum = Value

  val SubA, SubB, SubC = Value
}

object SomeTopEnum extends Enumeration {
  type SomeTopEnum = Value

  val TopA = Value("TopA", Subs = List(SomeSubEnum.SubA, SomeSubEnum.SubB))
  val TopB = Value("TopB", Subs = List(SomeSubEnum.SubC))
  val TopC = Value("TopC", Subs = List(SomeSubEnum.SubA, SomeSubEnum.SubB, SomeSubEnum.SubC))
}
```

Usage:

```
def doSomething(param: SomeTopEnum) = {
  someTopEnum.Subs.forAll(sub => doMore(sub))
}


doSomethingElse(SomeTopEnum.TopA.Subs.SubB) // Subs could be a map
```

I am new at Scala, in other languages I would create a kind of static class tree structure to do that, but maybe there is a better solution in Scala.

[sorry for my poor English]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use case classes for this instead?  The enumeration type in Scala isn't generally that useful IMO.  Something along the lines of (off the top of my head):

```
sealed abstract class MyEnum[A]
case class SubEnum[A](value : A) extends MyEnum[A]
case class TopEnum[A](value : A, subs : List[SubEnum[A]]) extends MyEnum[A]
```

This would allow you to do things like:

```
val top = TopEnum("top value", List(SubEnum("sub value 1"), SubEnum("sub value 2")))
```

and then:

```
top.subs map (println(_))
```

or:

```
for(s <- top.subs) println(s.value)
```

Or any pattern matching you might want to do as well.  If you wanted to restrict the types of the type parameter (A) then you could define a top level case class which all sub classes must be a subtype of:

```
sealed abstract class EnumValue(a : String)
case class EnumValue1 extends EnumValue("value 1")
case class EnumValue2 extends EnumValue("value 2")

...etc....

sealed abstract class MyEnum[A <: EnumValue]
case class SubEnum[A <: EnumValue](value : A) extends MyEnum[A]
case class TopEnum[A <: EnumValue](value : A, List[SubEnum[A]]) extends MyEnum[A]
```

Bit verbose, but will probably do what you want...

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually, to give you a more flexible structure, you can simply just change the definition of TopEnum to:  case class TopEnum[A <: EnumValue](value : A, List[MyEnum[A]]) extends MyEnum[A].  That way, you could have a list of mixed TopEnums and SubEnums...

Comment: For additional Java enum like features in a nice package. See this guys post http://stackoverflow.com/a/27441788/1148030