# Getting all enum-y case object values in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection, enums, macros

In Scala, enums are a disputed area and many people (including myself) rather use `case object`s than any library-based enumeration. This is great, except for that one doesn't get a list of all possible values, which sometimes is needed. I've maintained such lists (`allKeys`) manually, but that is tedious and error-prone.

The question is: how can Scala 2.11 [TypeTags](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) or reflection be used, to create such a list?

One of two ways would work:

- getting all derived instances of a `sealed` class
- getting all `case object`s declared within a particular object

Note: There are [samples](https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/57add1cd762eb90f6b24) that seem to promise what I'm looking for. But that's overkill - there must be an almost one-liner to get the same?

Below is a test for this. How could I implement the `allOf` function?

```
class ManifestToolsTest extends UnitTest {

  behavior of "ManifestTools" {

    sealed class MyEnum

    object MyEnum {
      case object A extends MyEnum
      case object B extends MyEnum
      case object C extends MyEnum

      val x= 10           // should not be listed
      def f(x: Int) = x   // should not be listed
    }

    def allOf[T]: Seq[T] = {
      ...  
    }

    it should "be able to list the 'case object' members of an object" in {

      val tmp: Seq[MyEnum] = allOf[MyEnum]
      tmp should contain theSameElementsAs( List(MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B, MyEnum.C) )
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried to get this info from the Scala documentation, but when it comes to reflection, things are really abstract. I believe the above need is (should be) covered by Scala 2.11.

References:

- [Case objects vs Enumerations in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898932/case-objects-vs-enumerations-in-scala)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the [cure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898932/case-objects-vs-enumerations-in-scala/27441788#27441788), called Enumeratum, but thought I'd post this question anyhow to make it easier for people to find this new piece of macro jewelry.