# Scala Enum.values.map(_.id).contains(value) cost much time

Tags: scala, enums

I want to check if a specify id that contained in an `Enumeration`.
So I write down the `contains` function

```
object Enum extends Enumeration {
  type Enum = Value
  val A = Value(2, "A")

  def contains(value: Int): Boolean = {
    Enum.values.map(_.id).contains(value)
  }
}
```

But the time cost is unexpected while id is a big number, such as over eight-digit

```
val A = Value(222222222, "A")
```

Then the `contains` function cost over 1000ms per calling.

And I also noticed the first time calling always cost hundreds millisecond whether the id is big or small.

I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

First, lets talk about the cost of `Enum.values`. This is implemented here:

See here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/0b47dc2f28c997aed86d6f615da00f48913dd46c/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L83

The implementation is essentially setting up a mutable map. Once it is set up, it is re-used.

The cost for big numbers in your `Value` is because, internally Scala library uses a BitSet.

See here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/0b47dc2f28c997aed86d6f615da00f48913dd46c/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L245

So, for larger numbers, BitSet will be bigger. That only happens when you call `Enum.values`.

Depending on your specific uses case you can choose between using Enumeration or Case Object:

- [Case objects vs Enumerations in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898932/case-objects-vs-enumerations-in-scala)

Answer (score 1):

It sure looks like the mechanics of `Enumeration` don't handle large ints well in that position. The [Scaladocs for the class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration) don't say anything about this, but they don't advertise using `Enumeration.Value` the way you do either. They say, e.g., `val A = Value`, where you say `val A = Value(2000, "A")`.

If you want to keep your `contains` method as you have it, why don't you cache the `Enum.values.map(_.id)`? Much faster.

```
object mult extends App {

  object Enum extends Enumeration {
    type Enum = Value
    val A1 = Value(1, "A")
    val A2 = Value(2, "A")
    val A222 = Enum.Value(222222222, "A")
    def contains(value: Int): Boolean = {
      Enum.values.map(_.id).contains(value)
    }
    val cache = Enum.values.map(_.id)
    def contains2(value: Int): Boolean = {
      cache.contains(value)
    }
  }

  def clockit(desc: String, f: => Unit) = {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis
    f
    val end = System.currentTimeMillis
    println(s"$desc ${end - start}")
  }
  clockit("initialize Enum    ", Enum.A1)
  clockit("contains 2         ", Enum.contains(2))
  clockit("contains 222222222 ", Enum.contains(222222222))
  clockit("contains 222222222 ", Enum.contains(222222222))
  clockit("contains2 2        ", Enum.contains2(2))
  clockit("contains2 222222222", Enum.contains2(222222222))
}
```