# ordinal() method in scala Enumeration

Tags: scala, enums

in java i've got enum say

```
enum Num {
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE;

    private static Num current = ONE;
    private static Num next = TWO;

    public Num getNext(){
        return values()[(ordinal() + 1) % values().length];
    }

    public static Num getNextNum(){
       next = current.getNext()
    }
}
```

so i'm able to assign next in that fashion calling getNextNum(), but scala enums, as it seems to me, lacks this feature. do u know any other workaround except using java enum in scala code?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Case objects vs Enumerations in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898932/case-objects-vs-enumerations-in-scala)

In Scala, Enumeration has limited functionality and it's preferable to have sealed traits if you want to have functionality added to your Enumeration.
For example:

```
sealed trait Num {
  val next: Num
}
case object ONE extends Num {
  override val next = TWO
}
case object TWO extends Num {
  override val next = THREE
}
case object THREE extends Num {
  override lazy val next = ONE
}
```

Also in your case, it's a bit tricky since you want to refer to a value before it's initialized. So there is a lazy on the last definition (you can also define next as def, if you want to)

Answer (score 2):

In case you wanted to achieve this behavior using standard Scala `Enumeration`, you can redefine `Enumeration#Value` as instances of your enum:

```
object Num extends Enumeration {
  case class MyValue() extends Val {
    def next: MyValue = Num((id + 1) % Num.values.size).asInstanceOf[MyValue]
  }
  val One, Two, Three = MyValue()
}

Num.One.next
// res0: Num.MyValue = Two
```

However, since Enumerations are bad due to [so many reasons](http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2014/09/03/enumerations.html), as well as don't have consistent IDE support, I personally would use sealed traits with case objects for enums (check out [enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum)) which allow to introduce arbitrary logic for my enums due to precise control over what's going on.

Comment: that's what i'm looking for, but when i'm trying to change var current = current.next, it says that requiring type is MyValue.type buy the one it gets is Num.MyValue.