# Getting Scala enum instances

Tags: scala, enums, singleton

I have the following Scala enum which I designed [after reading this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1899887/4009451):

```
object RunMode extends Enumeration {
    val CLIENT_MODE = Value("CLIENT_MODE")
    val SERVER_MODE = Value("SERVER_MODE")
}
```

I am now trying to pass an instance of it as an argument into the constructor of another class:

```
package com.me.myapp.shared.config

import com.me.myapp.shared.utils.RunMode

class MyAppConfig(runMode : RunMode) {

}
```

This gives me a compiler error:

> *Cannot resolve symbol `RunMode`*

BTW: `com.me.myapp.shared.utils.RunMode` *is* the correct package path for `RunMode`, so that's **not** the issue here!

I *assume* that this is maybe because there is only (ever) one single instance of the `RunMode` object, and perhaps that prevents it from being passed in as an arg.

Either way, I don't really care what the solution is. But I need an "enum" called `RunMode` and I'll need to be able to pass instances of it into contructors of other classes. Any ideas?

Comment: I've written a small overview about scala Enumeration and alternatives, you may find it useful: pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-enums/ and http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-enums-part2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, the correct type for a value of an `Enumeration` is `Enumeration.Value`, so here you need to use:

```
class MyAppConfig(runMode : RunMode.Value) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're correct in the assumption that the only instance that inhabits the type `RunMode` is the `object` itself.

However fixing your problem isn't all that difficult.

```
object RunMode extends Enumeration {
  type RunMode = Value
  val CLIENT_MODE = Value("CLIENT_MODE")
  val SERVER_MODE = Value("SERVER_MODE")
}
```

The `Enumeration` class gives you the type `Value` which is the type that all of your enumerated types should have. It's scoped to the class instance, so every instance of `Enumeration` get's its own `Value` type.

You can give it a proper name by creating a type alias.
Then you can import the inner type alias like this:

```
import com.me.myapp.shared.utils.RunMode._
```

And then you can pass Instances of your `Enumeration` around, therefore also allowing you to keep the `MyAppConfig` the same as it is right now.

Alternatively, you could of course also omit the type alias and just change the type signature of `MyAppConfig` to `RunMode.Value`. However I believe the former method is much better at clarifying intent.

```
class MyAppConfig(runMode: RunMode.Value) {

}
```