# Scala enumerations with Singleton objects as enumeration elements and a possibility to iterate over them?

Tags: java, reflection, scala, enums

I already looked at the [Scala question about emulating Java's `enum`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321745/scala-doesnt-have-enums-what-to-use-instead-of-an-enum) and [case classes vs. Enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898932/case-classes-vs-enumerations-in-scala) but It seems too much effort for too less benefit.

Basically I would like to have a `values` method returning all singleton objects of `DayOfWeek` without repeating myself a few times.

This is how my code should look like:

```
object DayOfWeek extends MyEnum {
  object MONDAY extends DayOfWeek(1)
  object TUESDAY extends DayOfWeek(2)
  object WEDNESDAY extends DayOfWeek(3)
  object THURSDAY extends DayOfWeek(4)
  object FRIDAY extends DayOfWeek(5)
  object SATURDAY extends DayOfWeek(6)
  object SUNDAY extends DayOfWeek(7)
}

class DayOfWeek(ordinal: Int)
```

The method `values` should return something like if it had been written like this:

```
val values = Array(MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY,
                   FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY)
```

Everything should happen in the `MyEnum` trait so I only need to extend it to get the functionality.

```
trait MyEnum {
  val values = this.getClass.getField("MODULE$") etc. etc.
}
```

Any suggestion how this could be done exactly?
The idea is that `values` accesses the class and finds all singleton objects of the class they are extending.

**Edit: It looks like all suggestions don't take in account that the user can create objects too which should of course be comparable to the defined ones.**

I'll try to give another example, maybe it is more clear:

```
object MonthDay extends MyEnum {
  //Some important holidays
  object NewYear       extends MonthDay( 1,  1)
  object UnityDay      extends MonthDay(11,  9)
  object SaintNicholas extends MonthDay(12,  6)
  object Christmas     extends MonthDay(12, 24)
}

class MonthDay(month: Int, day: Int)

//Of course the user can create other MonthDays
val myBirthDay = new MonthDay(month, day)

if(!MonthDay.values.contains(myBirthDay)) "Well, I probably have to work"
else "Great, it is a holiday!"
```

I want to have a trait (`MyEnum`) which I can mix into the object holding my "enumeration objects" with methods to return a list of them (`def values: List[MonthDay]`) or iterate over them (`def next: MonthDay` or `def previous: MonthDay`).

**PPS: [I created a new question for the second part of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239594/how-to-access-objects-within-an-object-by-mixing-in-a-trait-with-reflection)** as requested by Ken Bloom.

Comment: could you re-ask your amended question as a new question (phrased as a reflection question)? It really has nothing to do with Enumerations.

Comment: the `add` function that I proposed is still a workable solution to your amended question.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: Done, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239594/how-to-access-objects-within-an-object-by-mixing-in-a-trait-with-reflection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this? It requires you to actually call an `add` method for each new value, but `values` returns the right type.

```
abstract class MyEnum{

   type Value     //define me to be the value type for this MyEnum

   private var _values:List[Value] = Nil
   def values = _values    
   protected def add(newValue:Value) = {
      _values = newValue::_values
      newValue
   }
}

object DayOfWeek extends MyEnum{
   class Value(val dayNum:Int)
   val SUNDAY    = add(new Value(1))
   val MONDAY    = add(new Value(2))
   val TUESDAY   = add(new Value(3))
   val WEDNESDAY = add(new Value(4))
   val THURSDAY  = add(new Value(5))
   val FRIDAY    = add(new Value(6))
   val SATURDAY  = add(new Value(7))
}
```

You can now call

```
println(DayOfWeek.values map (_.dayNum))
```

If you need singleton objects that have different definitions of the methods on different objects, you can create anonymous classes like so:

```
add(new Value{
      override def dayNum=8
    })
```

Comment: Just as a side point, you want to use a `var` of type `List[Value]` internally, rather than a `val` of type `Array[Value]`, because you want the list of values returned to the user to be totally immutable.

Answer (score 3):

[scala.Enumeration](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Enumeration.html) does exactly what you want already.

I think you may be confused by Scala 2.7 versus Scala 2.8. The old question you cite about [emulating Java's `enum`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321745/scala-doesnt-have-enums-what-to-use-instead-of-an-enum) was written in the days of Scala 2.7, and though I can't go test what functionality Scala 2.7's `Enumeration`s posessed, Scala 2.8's `Enumeration`s certainly possess everything you're looking for.

You can't define values with `object SUNDAY extends Value(1)` because `object`s are initialized lazily.

Comment: No. I looked at `scala.Enumeration` and it doesn't work. It is not possible to add methods to the corresponding class. Additionally user-instantiated instances of that class are not of the same type as the `Value`s from the Enumeration.

Comment: I stand corrected. I didn't realize the goal was to add user-defined methods to the `Value` class.

Comment: @soc I don't understand why you think you are unable to add methods to Val from enumeration. Please see pattern C in this answer I just posted to another thread (and consider that you could add any method you like to the case class ChessPieceVal which extends Val: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25923651/501113

Answer (score 2):

The closest I've been able to come up with is:

```
abstract class MyEnum(val displayName:String){
   protected object Value{
      var _values:List[Value] = Nil
      def values = _values
   }
   protected class Value (val value:Int){
      Value._values = this::Value._values
      override def toString = "%s(%d)".format(displayName,value)
   }
   def values = Value.values
}

trait Methods{
   def dayName
}

object DayOfWeek extends MyEnum("DayOfWeek"){
   val SUNDAY = new Value(1) with Methods{
      override def dayName = "Sunday"
   }
   val MONDAY = new Value(2) with Methods{
      override def dayName = "Monday"
   }
   val TUESDAY = new Value(3) with Methods{
      override def dayName = "Tuesday"
   }
   val WEDNESDAY = new Value(4) with Methods{
      override def dayName = "Wednesday"
   }
   val THURSDAY = new Value(5) with Methods{
      override def dayName = "Thursday"
   }
   val FRIDAY = new Value(6) with Methods{
      override def dayName = "Friday"
   }
   val SATURDAY = new Value(7) with Methods{
      override def dayName = "Saturday"
   }
}
```

I haven't figured out how to change the type of the `_values` variable to capture the full type `Value with Methods`.