# How to reflect Enumeration class in scala?

Tags: scala, oop, reflection, enums, enumeration

I have a Scala Enumeration and I want to get the Enumeration value from `String`.

```
object CVVStatus extends Enumeration {
  type CVVStatus = Value
  val PRESENT, NOT_PRESENT, VALID, INVALID = Value
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
val prop = new Properties()
prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.conf"))
val tmp = prop.getProperty(propname)
val s:CVVStatus = StringtoEmum(tmp)
```

If I need lots of enumeration from different Enumeration object-name to enumeration objects, how should I accomplish this? What package should I import?

Comment: No packages, it comes for free. `.withName` is the method you are looking for. `val s:CVVStatus = CVVStatus.withName(tmp)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alec points out in a comment, this is 'for free' with the [Enumeration class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.Enumeration), and it is easy to see in a worksheet:

```
object CVVStatus extends Enumeration {
  type CVVStatus = Value
  val PRESENT, NOT_PRESENT, VALID, INVALID = Value
}

val test_present = "PRESENT"  // test_present: String = PRESENT
val test_incorrect = "INCORRECT"  // test_incorrect: String = INCORRECT
val enumeration_present = CVVStatus.withName(test_present)  // enumeration_present: CVVStatus.Value = PRESENT
val enumeration_incorrect = CVVStatus.withName(test_incorrect)  //java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value found for 'INCORRECT'
```

This last one fails, because it is not a valid enumeration. The `withName` documentation reads:

> Return a Value from this Enumeration whose name matches the argument s. The names are determined automatically via reflection.

No imports necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using case objects. For reference, check these stackoverflow answers
[Case Objects vs Enumerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898932/case-objects-vs-enumerations-in-scala)
[How to access objects within an object by mixing in a trait with reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239594/how-to-access-objects-within-an-object-by-mixing-in-a-trait-with-reflection)