# How to add reusable field to Scala Enumeration?

Tags: scala, enums, field, reusability, extending

I would like to extend Scala's implementation of `Enumeration` with a custom field, say `label`. That new field should be accessible via the `values` of that enumeration. Furthermore, that custom field should be part of various implementations of `Enumeration`.

I am aware of the following questions at Stackoverflow:

- [How to add a method to Enumeration in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4346580/66981)
- [How do I create an enum in scala that has an extra field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6473445/66981)
- [Overriding Scala Enumeration Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2507273/66981)
- [Scala doesn't have enums - what to use instead of an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1321745/66981)

However, none of them solves my issues:

The first issue is that I am able to add a custom field. However, I cannot access that additional field via the `Values` returned by `Enumeration.values`. The following code works and prints `2nd enumeration value`:

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
  type MyEnum = MyVal
  val VALUE_ONE = MyVal()
  val VALUE_TWO = MyVal(Some("2nd enumeration value"))
  val VALUE_THREE = MyVal(Some("3rd value"))

  case class MyVal(label: Option[String] = None) extends Val(nextId)
}
import MyEnum._

println(VALUE_TWO.label.get)
```

Note that I access the label via one of the values. The following code does not work:

```
for (value <- MyEnum.values) println(value.label)
```

The error message is as follows: `error: value label is not a member of MyEnum.Value`

Obviously, instead of `MyEnum.MyVal`, `MyEnum.Val` is used. The latter does not define `label`, while my custom value would provide field `label`.

The second issue is that it seems to be possible to introduce a custom `Value` and `Val`, respectively, in the context of an `Enumeration` only. Thus, as far as I know, it is not possible to use such a field across different enums. At least, the following code does not compile:

```
case class MyVal(label: Option[String] = None) extends Enumeration.Val(nextId)

object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
  type MyEnum = MyVal
  val VALUE_ONE = MyVal()
  val VALUE_TWO = MyVal(Some("2nd enumeration value"))
}

object MySecondEnum extends Enumeration {
  type MySecondEnum = MyVal
  val VALUE_ONE = MyVal()
  val VALUE_TWO = MyVal(Some("2nd enumeration value"))
}
```

Due to the fact that class `Val` is protected, case class `MyVal` cannot access `Val` -- `MyVal` is not defined in the context of an enumeration.

Any idea how to solve the above issues?

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is addressed by a recent question, [my answer to which got no love](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23122560/1296806).

For that use case, I would write a custom `widgets` method with the useful type, but my linked answer, which just introduces an implicit conversion, seems pretty handy.  I don't know why it's not the canonical solution.

For the second issue, your derived `MyVal` should just implement a trait.

Sample:

```
scala> trait Labelled { def label: Option[String] }
defined trait Labelled

scala> object A extends Enumeration { case class AA(label: Option[String]) extends Val with Labelled ; val X = AA(Some("one")) }
defined object A

scala> object B extends Enumeration { case class BB(label: Option[String]) extends Val with Labelled ; val Y = BB(None) }
defined object B

scala> val labels = List(A.X, B.Y)
labels: List[Enumeration#Val with Product with Labelled] = List(X, Y)

scala> labels map (_.label)
res0: List[Option[String]] = List(Some(one), None)
```