# Scala/Java enumerations

Tags: java, scala, enums, idioms

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321745/scala-doesnt-have-enums-what-to-use-instead-of-an-enum) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898932/case-classes-vs-enumerations-in-scala), but I still don't understand the (idiomatic) equivalent way to do this in Scala

```
enum Status { 
    OK(1, "Ok", "Okay"),
    NOT_OK(5, "Not Ok", "Not Okay")
    BAD(10, "Bad", "Run for your life")

    int code;
    String name;
    String description; // custom fields

    Status(int code, String name, String description) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(Status status : Status.values) { // iterate through them
            doStuff(status);
        }
    }

    private doStuff(Status status) {
        System.out.println(status.description);
        // and more
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the question title is wrong

Comment: I don't understand what etag values and nginx have to do with Scala enumerations.   An etag is a server generated hash value that an HTTP client can use to detect if content has changed.

Comment: Oh man, that was embarrassing. I was going to ask a question "Can Nginx ETag proxied content?" last week, but I discarded it after writing just the title. When asked this question, it apparently was already set as the title.

Answer (score 10):

In Scala you can create a Enumeration structure which is close to "enum" from Java. Basically, what you need to do is just to extend a [scala.Enumeration class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration) and to extend a Val class if you need a more complicated class as a enum. Otherwise, you can use default Val class which takes Int or String or Both. Below, is a Scala version of your Java code.

```
object Status extends Enumeration {

  case class StatusVal(code: Int, name: String, description: String) extends Val

  val OK = StatusVal(1, "Ok", "Okay")
  val NOT_OK = StatusVal(1, "Not Ok", "Not Okay")
  val BAD = StatusVal(1, "Bad", "Run for your life")
}

object Application extends App {
  Status.values foreach (s => println(s.asInstanceOf[StatusVal].description))
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use 1 as the ID for each StatusVal?  Also, would it be better for StatusVal to extend `Val(code, name)`?

Comment: @mrog, no, `1` is just a typo. You can use any Int.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct mapping between case class and enumerations or something really close to enumerations either. But you can implement similar logic this way:

```
case class Status(code: Int, name: String, descr: String)
object Status {
 val OK = Status(1, "Ok", "Okay"),
 val NOT_OK = Status(5, "Not Ok", "Not Okay")
 val BAD = Status(10, "Bad", "Run for your life")
}
```

Then if you want you can place it in some list called values:

```
import Status._
val values = List(OK, NOT_OK, BAD)
```

and then do your stuff:

```
values.foreach(doStuff)
```

The result would be the same like in Java version

If you need to execute different actions which depends on type of Status, then you can go with pattern matching:

```
sealed trait Status
case class OK(code: Int, name: String, descr: String) extends Status
case class Not_Ok(code: Int, name: String, descr: String) extends Status
case class Bad(code: Int, name: String, descr: String) extends Status
```

then in your doStuff function use pattern matching, e.g:

```
def doStuff(status: Status) = status match {
  case OK(c, n, d) => // some code..
  // some code for other cases
}

val values = List(OK(1, "Ok", "Okay"), Not_Ok(5, "Not Ok", "Not Okay"), Bad(10, "Bad", "Run for your life"))

value.foreach(doStuff)
```

Comment: I prefer your `sealed trait Status` approach, but I'd use `case object` instead of `case class` to declare the three "enum" values.

Comment: @DaoWen in case of case objects extending a trait or a class, you won't have implicit apply/unapply for pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sealed class` + `case object`. The only part you can't get with this approach is method `values`, but you could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13672520/406435) to implement method `values` like this:

```
sealed class Status(val code: Int, val name: String, val description: String)
object Status {
  def values: Set[Status] = macro SealedExample.values_impl[Status]

  case object OK extends Status(1, "Ok", "Okay")
  case object NOT_OK extends Status(5, "Not Ok", "Not Okay")
  case object BAD extends Status(10, "Bad", "Run for your life")
}

def doStuff(status: Status) = println(status.description)

for {s <- Status.values}
  doStuff(s)
// Okay
// Not Okay
// Run for your life
```