# Multiple Values for one enum

Tags: scala, enums, enumeration

So I am creating a parser to parse some configuration files made by our client engineers. I don't particularly trust our client engineers. They can usually spell things right but they can never remember what to capitalize. This makes `Enum` classes kind of noisome in that they go and break the program cause the `Enum` fails if they don't type in the exact right string.

Here is my Enum Class:

```
object EnumLayoutAlignment extends Enumeration
{
     type Alignment = Value
     val Vertical = Value("Vertical")
     val Horizontal = Value("Horizontal")
}
```

Is there a way I could make it so that "Vertical", "vertical", and "VERTICAL" all mapped to the same enum value?

EDIT: @Radai brought up a good point of just .upper() on the input but I would also like to include "vert" and other similar inputs

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321745/scala-doesnt-have-enums-what-to-use-instead-of-an-enum) as an example

Comment: why not simply uppercase everything?

Comment: The problem is that our client engineers still won't remember that... With all due respect to them I want this to be user proof

Comment: i meant take their input (==any value your code reads from a conf file), and uppercase it. or do you mean they will be using the code directly and not some interface that you control?

Comment: @radai not a bad idea but I would also like to add a couple of other possible mappings

Comment: Why use Enum instead of abstract data types in functional languages?

Comment: @Naetmul Looking here: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/105 I don't understand the benefit of that?

Comment: Are you looking for Scala-specific implementation or is it ok to be straight up Java?

Comment: @gtgaxiola There is a preference for Scala

Comment: Other than normalizing case before getting the enum value, the best option is probably to create an explicit map from `String -> EnumLayoutAlignment`. For instance, you may want to map "vert" to `Vertical`.

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot I meant case classes and case objects - abstract data types like http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Abstract_data_type not abstract types. Maybe it is better to say algebraic data types. http://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2011/01/30/functional-scala-algebraic-datatypes-enumerated-types/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to handle this is to provide a method for deserialization:

```
def fromString(s: String) = s.upper() match {
  case "VERTICAL" | "VERT" | "V" => Some(Vertical)
  case "HORIZONTAL" | "HORIZ" | "H" => Some(Horizontal)
  case => None
}
```

Then using it is as simple as:

```
EnumLayoutAlignment.fromString(someInput).map(doThingWithValidEnum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method like this to your `Enumeration`:

```
def tryAsHardAsPossibleToFindMatch(s: String) = {
  val ls = s.toLowerCase
  val fv = values.filter(_.toString.toLowerCase.startsWith(ls))
  fv.size match {
    case 1 => fv.head
    case 0 => sys.error("No matching value for " + s)
    case _ => sys.error("Ambiguous values for " + s)
  }
}
```

This will allow you to use any string, regardless of case, that is part of the beginning of a `Value`. So `Vertical` can be obtained with "VERT", "vErTi", "vERTICAL", "VerticaL", etc.