# How to model finite set of values of enum-like type for (de)serialization?

Tags: json, scala, enums, spray-json

I am using Spray-json 1.3.1. I have the following JSON message:

```
{
   "results": [{
   ... NOT IMPORTANT PART HERE ...
   }],
   "status": "OK"
}
```

Trivially, this can be deserialized to `status` String field via

```
case class Message[T](results: List[T], status: String)
```

with custom Protocol

```
object MessageProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit def messageFormat[T: JsonFormat] = jsonFormat2(Message.apply[T])
}
```

Since `status` field can be one of `OK`, `ZERO_RESULTS`, `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` having this field as a String makes no sense. As I am coming from 
Java background I tried enums in Scala implemented as follows:

```
case class Message[T](results: List[T], status: Status)
object Status extends Enumeration{
  type Status = Value
  val OK,ZERO_RESULTS,OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, REQUEST_DENIED, INVALID_REQUEST,UNKNOWN_ERROR = Value
} 

object MessageProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val statusFormat = jsonFormat(Status)
  implicit def messageFormat[T: JsonFormat] = jsonFormat2(Message.apply[T])
}
```

What is best practice/approach to solve this?

Comment: I would take a look at Akka-Http as that is what spray became. They solved this using a singleton object and inheritance --> http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M2/#akka.http.model.StatusCodes$

Comment: Consider also case objects, as illustrated in the response from Daniel Sobral in thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321745/scala-doesnt-have-enums-what-to-use-instead-of-an-enum , as your approach creates dodgy serialization/deserialization issues (things like `` "status" : {"name" : "OK"} '' may appear here and there breaking everything, depending on your parser/serializer library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply implement your own RootJsonFormat (as an implicit in Message companion object) and override read and write functions. There you will have JsObject and you can convert it to your own case class as you want like converting the string to desired enumeration etc. You can see a sample [here](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-other-types)