# Naming convention about the Scala enumeration types?

Tags: scala, naming-conventions

What's the naming convention for a Scala enumeration type? For example, in the below code:

```
object EventType extends Enumeration {
    type EventType = Value

    val Registered = Value("Registered")
    val Started = Value("Started")
}

/**
 * The event that fires under specific life cycle
 *
 * @param eventType the [[EventType.EventType]]
 */
 case class Event(eventType: EventType.EventType)
```

The above code follows the same style as described in the [Scala doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration). The question here is you can see the name of "EventType.EventType" is quite redundant and also quite strange when compared with enum definitions in other languages like Java or C#.

So I'm wondering if there is any recommended naming style to improve the readability?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might already be aware of this but a lot of scala programmers avoid the Enumeration class and instead use a sealed base type and case objects for the possible values. If you are interested you can read more in the answers of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321745/how-to-model-type-safe-enum-types

Comment: Really appreciate your comment. I learnt a lot from this thread

Answer (score 1):

To shorten it you can use import with an underscore to import everything from the object `EventType`. So instead of `import EventType` you would use `import EventType._`. Here is an example:

```
scala> object EventType extends Enumeration {
     |     type EventType = Value
     |
     |     val Registered = Value("Registered")
     |     val Started = Value("Started")
     | }
defined object EventType

scala> object Test {
     | import EventType._
     |
     | case class Event(eventType: EventType)
     | }
defined object Test
```

Things might seem confusing because `EventType` is the name of the object and `EventType.EventType` is the type of the enum. So if you use it this way:

```
EventType.Registered
```

then in this case it's the name of the object, not the type. On contrary, here:

```
case class Event(eventType: EventType)
```

it's the name of the type, i.e. the one defined with `type EventType`.

If you want to avoid confusion you can give a different name to the type:

```
scala> object Events extends Enumeration {
     |           type EventType = Value
     |           val Registered = Value("Registered")
     |           val Started = Value("Started")
     | }
defined object Events
scala> object Test {
     | import Events._
     | case class Event(eventType: EventType)
     | val a = Event(Registered)
     | }
defined object Test
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However this is somehow tricky.... The "import" does not solve the readability issue: there's EventType.Registered and EventType.Started which make others think the "EventType" itself is the "enum" type, but in the Scala world, the "EventType.EventType" is in fact the real type.